# Blazor wasm An unhandled error has occurred When using Chrome 91 on android

Tags: android, google-chrome, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

My Blazor wasm web app stuck at the paging saying "Loading..." in the top left-hand corner throws An unhandled error has occurred. this only happens When using Chrome 91 on android. When I test the site on the Samsung web browser it works. was also working on the older version of chrome. It even works on chrome 91 when I connect my phone to my computer in development to try and look at the console log.

its running dotnet 5.0.6

does anyone know of the problem? or have any ideas of why it may be happening. if you need more information to help resolve the problem please let me know thanks.

Comment: It's definitely related to Chrome 91 on Android. Whatever those performance optimizations entailed seems to have broken Blazor WASM apps.

Comment: Same problem here. I've been trying to fix it but no luck. Any solutions yet?

Comment: @JorgeZuverza I'm still trying to find a fix myself.  Dave is saying the problem goes away in .NET 6 Preview 4 but I can't use Preview for my production app.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. The tab becomes completely unresponsive. It's incredibly frustrating when it won't repo while remote debugging. I know this isn't an acceptable solution, but wanted to at least share that the problem goes away after upgrading to .NET 6 Preview 4.